# Neural Nets: Calculating Error In Hidden Layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I am new to neural nets and am attempting to build an ultra-simple neural network with more than 1 hidden layer.

When adjusting the weights during the training phase of a neural network, the degree by which the weights are adjusted is partially dependent on "how much error" this neuron contributed to the next layer of neurons. Thus, we need to know the error of the next layer.

Calculating this is trivial with only 1 hidden layer, as our training data already provides us with the expected outputs and so we need only use the output layer (simply, target-out). Calculating error becomes non-trivial when there are multiple hidden layers. That is, if we have 10 hidden layers and we are in layer 5, how do we know what the error of layer 6 is?

Thanks

Comment: Are you refering to the Error derivatives of layer 6 weights with respect to the loss Function?

Comment: Then it should be easily derived by using Backpropagation

Comment: I believe so, again I'm fairly new to this. The error for a neuron in a layer is calculated to be approximately (target - out)^2. I want to know how to calculate target for some neuron in layer 6.

Comment: I'm writing a full answer addressing all the process

Comment: I'm trying to address a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430571/neural-network-how-to-calculate-the-error-for-a-unit. I came across this answer, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my question. If someone had the time to look at the question I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose our NN output values [image] and the actual ground truth [image] are related by a loss function, *e.g.,* Mean Squared error (Regression case):

[image]

Where:

[image]

[image] and [image] are the weights of layer [image], and [image] is an activation function applied to all neuron responses at the same layer.

To propagate the error on the model weights from the output layer, we simply can apply the chain rule between the error loss function and the factor that depends on a model parameter (Weight or bias). For instance, let's find the error derivative that relates the loss function and the weights of the output layer:  [image] as it follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can infer, we can apply the same procedure to calculate the error derivatives, via each activation [image] up to the lower layers of the network. For example, let's backpropagate the error up to layer [image]:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This process can be applied also to bias, up to the layer before the input layer [image].

I hope this backpropagation summary gives you some practical insight about the actual implementation of a Neural Network, on this case, a Feed Forward NN. If you want to have more detailed information about backpropagation, I invite you to consult the Stanford's UFLDL [tutorial](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Backpropagation_Algorithm) on backpropagation:

Also, if you want to learn more about Convolutional Neural Nets, which are more suitable to Computer Vision applications, I recommend the CS231n course notes (Which also have a lesson on backpropagation), they are available at [here](http://cs231n.github.io/).

Comment: does this actually answer the question of error at each layer?  It seems like you just tell us how to get gradients for theta using the chain rule.