# How are the biases updated in a two layer perceptron model using logistic sigmoid function.

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am relatively new to Machine Learning. I am trying to implement a two layer perceptron model, which has 4 binary inputs, 1 hidden layer with 4 neurons and one output layer. 
During back-prop I am using the delta rule to update the weights for the output layer and hidden layer which is as follows
Output layer: 
wj,k = wj,k + eta * delta_k * output_j
k is the output layer neuron (which in my case is only one) , j is a hidden layer neuron 
Hidden layer:
wi,j = wi,j + eta * delta_j * input_i
Could someone please guide me to a source or explain how the bias terms are updated?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554095/neural-nets-calculating-error-in-hidden-layers/43554664#43554664