# Neural network: How to calculate the error for a unit

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to work out question 26 from [this](http://130.243.105.49/%7Etdt/ann/tentor/exam2002.pdf) exam paper (the exam is from 2002, not one I'm getting marked on!)

This is the exact question:

[image]

The answer is B.

Could someone point out where I'm going wrong?

I worked out I1 from the previous question on the paper to be 0.982.

The activation function is sigmoid. So should the sum be, for output 1:

```
d1 = f(Ik)[1-f(Ik)](Tk-Zk)
```

From the question:

```
T1 = 0.58
Z1 = 0.83
T1 - Z1 = -0.25
sigmoid(I1) = sigmoid(0.982) = 0.728
1-sigmoid(I1) = 1-0.728 = 0.272
```

So putting this all together:

```
d1 = (0.728)(0.272)(-0.25)
d1 = -0.049
```

But the answer should be d1 = -0.0353

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Edit 1: I tried to work backwards to understand the situation, but I still got stuck.

I said:

```
d1 = f(Ik)[1-f(Ik)](Tk-Zk)
-0.0353 = f'(Ik)(-0.25) (where I know -0.0353 is the right answer, and -0.25 is Tk - Zk)
0.1412 = f'(Ik)
0.1412 = f(Ik)[1-f(Ik)]
0.1412 = sigmoid(x).(1-sigmoid(x))
```

...but then I got stuck, if anyone has an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that the `I₁` you got from the previous question is **not** the same `I₁` you need for this task.

The value of `I₁` changes depending on the input values(which are different for this question)!

For the solution of this question you can instead use the fact that `f(Iₖ) = zₖ`:

`δₖ   = f(Iₖ)·[1 - f(Iₖ)]·(tₖ - zₖ)`

`= zₖ·[1 - zₖ]·(tₖ - zₖ)`

`→ δ₁ = 0.83·[1 - 0.83]·(-0.25) = -0.2075·0.17 = -0.035275 ≈ -0.0353`

`→ δ₂ = 0.26·[1 - 0.26]·(0.70 - 0.26) ≈ -0.0847`

`→ δ₃ = 0.56·[1 - 0.56]·(0.20 - 0.56) ≈ -0.0887`

Comment: Sorry, I thought me accepting the answer automatically awarded the bounty. Thanks so much for this.